# Simplifying a result obtained after integrating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \theta^2 \sqrt{\cot\left(\theta\right)} \ d\theta$ using complex methods

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'd like to ask for a little hint on how to proceed with this result.

In an attempt to evaluate the integral in title I introduced the following auxiliary integral: $$I\left(a\right)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}\left(a^2+x^2\right)}\ dx$$
which for $\mathit a=1$ gives us the value that we seek. I then defined a complex valued function: $$\mathit f\left(z\right)=-\frac{1}{4}{\log^2\left(i-z\over i+z\right)\over\sqrt{z}\left(z^2+a^2\right)}$$
$$\arg\left(i-z\over i+z\right)\in\left(0,2\pi\right)$$
$$\arg\left(z\right)\in\left(0,2\pi\right)$$
$$a>1$$
with the arguments and values of $a$ as such, so that I could use the approach in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007015/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-the-integral-i-int-0-infty-frac-sqrtx-arctanx?noredirect=1&lq=1), using the same contour.

After doing all of the necessary manipulations, I'm left with the following expression: $$2I\left(a\right)+\int_0^1\left[\pi\sqrt2\log\left({1-y\over 1+y}\right)+\pi^2\sqrt2\right]\ {dy\over\sqrt y\left(a^2-y^2\right)}={\pi\sqrt a\over4a^2}\left[\pi^2\sqrt{2}-2\pi\sqrt{2}\log\left({a-1\over a+1}\right)-\sqrt{2}\log^2\left({a-1\over a+1}\right) \right]$$
with the right hand side representing the sum of the residues (multiplied by $2\pi i$) of the function $f\left(z\right)$ at $z=ia$ and $z=-ia$.

As we let $a$ approach 1 from above, it seems to agree numerically, but I'd like to ask for a tip on how to simplify this gnarly looking thing.

For reference, the integral in title should evaluate to: $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}\left(\frac{5\pi^3}{12}-\pi^2\log\left(2\right)-\pi\log^2\left(2\right)\right)$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $$\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{96}\left(5\pi^2-12\pi\ln(2)-12(\ln2)^2\right)$$
Seems to be the answer, not the one provided by OP.
The integral has been evaluated at this [AoPS Post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1760181p11504435)

Comment: Woops, I forgot about the 5 in front of $\frac{\pi^3}{12}$. These two results should now be equivalent, I'm terribly sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Possibly off the topic, but it seems that the formula $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\cos (p x) \sin ^{s-1}(x) dx=-\frac{2^{1-s}\pi~ \cos \left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right) \Gamma (s)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1+s-p}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1+s+p}{2}\right)}$ leads to a quick solution to the original integral (via differentiating w.r.t $p$ twice, plugging in $p=s=\dfrac12$ and a little algebra).